# iphone linked to an appleID

Tags: itunes, apple-id, iphone

I purchased an iPhone 6s second hand and the person whom I purchased is now in London. (I am in India)

When I restart the phone, it says this iPhone is currently linked to an appleID.

When I asked the person what's the appleID of the phone, he says that it doesn't have any but the phone shows something like this :

[image: This iPhone is linked to an appleid issue]

What do I do ?

How do I get my phone to work ?

Anyone please help I also tried putting the phone in DFU mode (press home button + lock button) and then installed the ipsw through itunes, still the above screen appeared.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no other way to make your phone work. It has to be unlocked first by the Apple ID mentioned on the screen. You should have checked iCloud activation lock status of the phone before purchasing.

If you have the original receipt of the phone from the seller, then you can approach Apple to reset your phone. Otherwise, there is no way to unlock it.